# Does importing Django.db.Models affect the way cx_Oracle connects to other databases?

Tags: django, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a Django app that uses cx_Oracle as the backend using an Oracle db here in our office, but it also uses cx_Oracle directly, to connect to other remote Oracle databases (our customers).  Some of the remote databases ( always the same few ) cannot be connected to after I have created any sub-class of django.db.Models ( I found this out through trial-and-error )

If I don't import my models, or if I change the django db from "oracle" to something else, then everything works fine and I can connect to all of the remote databases.  So something in the Django Model code seems to be affecting cx_Oracle in a global way.

Here's one clue that I have:  I used wireshark to compare a successful connection to an unsuccessful connection, and I found that the unsuccessful connection attempt did include what looked like some sort of "handshake" coming back from the server initially, but then the client sent a lot of "ALTER SESSION...NLS_DATE_FORMAT",  and many other "NLS" settings, etc.  After that the server never responds.  Those NSL are not there during the successful attempts.

The really confusing part of it is that only the "bad" databases ( the few that have the problem ) get all of those ALTER SESSION commands during connection.  The "good" databases don't get those, even after I have imported Models.  I have searched for differences between the "good" and "bad" databases ( NLS settings, DB settings, DB version, etc ), but they are all the same.

It is a huge mystery to me.  I am thinking about moving my actual Django DB over to MySQL, just to avoid the problem -- but that is crazy -- we are an Oracle shop, and we already have many Oracle databases running.

So the question is this:
Does the base django.db.oracle code do something to cx_Oracle that affects the way it connects?
What could it possibly be doing?
What could be the difference between my "bad" databases and my "good" ones?
They are all practically identical, and they all work fine for everyone except Django.
They all work fine with cx_Oracle, as long as I never import any Models.

EDIT:

To fix this problem, I have switched the Django backend from Oracle to MySQL.
I installed MySQL directly on my web server, and migrated all of my data using Django's "dumpdata" and "loaddata" tools.  It was surprisingly easy.  Now I am able to connect to ALL of my remote Oracle databases with no problem, because Django no longer messes with my Python/Oracle driver.
My app is slightly faster too, because the db is now on the same box as the web server.
I would recommend this solution for anyone in this situation.